# problems in debugging java source code 1.8 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

**Problem 1**: My eclipse suddenly stopped stepping into the java source code which used to be doing earlier i attaching source src.zip from jdk etc.. but still not stepping.
How shall i fix this problem.

**Problem 2:** I tried to compile the src.zip from jdk so as to enable the inspecting the java source code 1.8 by following some old posts but compiling with following options is giving some 100 errors. How shall i fix this ?

javac -verbose -J-Xmx1024m -cp "e:\programs1\jre\lib\rt.jar" -d "e:\java_src\output" -g @files.txt

[total 76959ms] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

**100 errors
100 warnings**

Comment: S1: Use F5(eclipse) while debugging and it will work

Comment: S2: You need not compile java source code to make your compiler detect it.

Comment: S1: refreshed still not working. s2: I tried to compile with -g  for inspecting the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:** check that step filtering is set up as needed or disabled at all in Eclipse. I think that by default the debugger is configured to step over methods of standard packages ("java", "javax", ...).

```
Window > Preferences > Java . Debug > Step filtering
```

The debugger will **not** enter in the classes of packages selected in above preferences.

**Problem 2:**  I never had the need to compile the source code... not so trivial since not all classes are included in src.zip (as I know). The *errors* you listed are more like warnings, but maybe you need to include the `-Xdiags:verbose` (as suggested) to get the real errors.

Comment: thanks for help Step filtering settings are correct in my case i tried various options in eclipse finally it is working in intellij community edition there i can debug and inspect the source even.